# Floating textbox in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, vba

I am using excel 2010. I have a textbox with a multi-color message in it.

[image]

I would like for it to stay in place when I scroll through my worksheet.

I've searched google for it and came up with this solution:

http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_excel-mso_other/how-to-create-a-floating-text-box-in-excel/59c7533c-c5b3-4096-bef2-4e9bac2176bf?auth=1

It uses userforms and textboxes from VBA. My question now is: how can I give the text that is displayed in the textbox a certain color (so that it matches the text box I already have)? And if this is not possible, how can I 'lock' the text box I have to keep it visible at all times?

**Edit**

It was suggested to use an activeX textbox and I tried that, but I don't know which property I should change.

[image: View of my excel file and the textbox I'm try to edit]

Comment: I am using a text box from the insert tab and then shapes. I'll try using a macro to see what code changes the color!

Comment: @ejbytes I tried recording a macro to change the text in my textbox, but I don't know how to modify it to change the text in my userform. I also tried running the floating text box with the userform and the recording a macro to change the color of it. But it was impossible to change the color.

Comment: @ejbytes I tried using an ActiveX textbox, but I still can't give it color, do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

To change the color of the text in a userform, use this line:

```
userFormName.TextBox1.ForeColor = &H00AABBCC&
```

Where *userFormName* is the name of the form, and *TextBox1* is the name of the object you want to change color of.

The first 2 zero's in the &H value are used to flag whether the colour is a system colour, like button face or windows background.
AABBCC is like a normal hex RGB code, but backwards.
AA is blue, BB is Green and CC is the value for red.
So &H000000FF& would be red.